# How Can a product model get its eav Attribute in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, eav, resource-model

I added a custom field to product in admin panel named `vendor_name`
So I wanna get value of this field by do something like

```
$_product->getVendorName()
```

Like what I can do with non eav attribute (i.e `$product->getSku()`)
But `$_product->getVendorName()` give me `null` value ,
What is the best solution to get attribute ? I wanna same syntax for both eav and None eav attribute.

Comment: is your catalog flat table enabled for the application ?

Comment: No it is not and i am in developer mode.

Answer (score 1):

In *Store > Attributes > Product > YOUR ATTRIBUTE > Storefront Properties* set **Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront** and **Used in Product Listing** to TRUE.

In your code you can use:

```
<?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getYourAttribute(), 'your_attribute') ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $_product->getYourAttribute() ?>
```

Comment: I wanna use this code <?php echo $_product->getYourAttribute() ?>
In this class magento/catalog/helper/image , in this class $product will loaded and given by the argument of the init function here is a code: 
{public function init($product, $imageId, $attributes = [])}
so when I debug the code the $_data of $product has only original attribute of a product model not custom (EAV) attribute .